# Run tensorflow lite model from tensorflow hub android

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have downloaded the Keras ocr tflite model (https://tfhub.dev/tulasiram58827/lite-model/keras-ocr/dr/2) from the TensorFlow hub and I would like to use it on my android app for scene text detection. But I a bit lost here since all the resources that I check about using TensorFlow lite on android say to use a labels file with the tflite model. But since the model is downloaded the model from the TensorFlow hub, I don't have a labels file. Is there any way I can run the tflite model on android without a label file?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just follow the post processing steps given in the [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tulasiram58827/ocr_tflite/blob/main/colabs/KERAS_OCR_TFLITE.ipynb).

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal in the colab example they used tf.lite.Interpreter to interpret the tflite model but I don't think I am able to use tensorflow core inside with android development.

Comment: I think you do not need this: `alphabets = string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase` `final_output = "".join(alphabets[index] for index in tflite_output[0] if index not in [blank_index, -1])` [link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tulasiram58827/ocr_tflite/blob/main/colabs/KERAS_OCR_TFLITE.ipynb#scrollTo=v6K9tv0u1umk&line=3&uniqifier=1)

Answer (score 0):

open git bash and enter the command `unzip your-name-model.tflite` and if you do not have it installed in your system, download it through the link below.
https://git-scm.com/downloads